How can I import a file on nodemon.json?
I want to add this statement in my nodemon.json exec:
--import ./instrumental.mjs

here is my code:
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts,json",
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
  "exec": "npx tsx src/server.ts"
}

if I add it to exec then its not working so how can I add --import ./instrumental.mjs in the exec script ?
